# Add file type to VS Code extension SCSS Formatter

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to add a file type (file extension) to the type of file that SCSS Formatter in VS Code will format as SASS? I would like to add ".scss.liquid" files to be formatted. For example "styles.scss.liquid"